# open notepad.exe in php

Tags: php, xampp, exec

I am using XAMPP server and for me required to open notepad.exe via.php and I have tried below codes and none of them are working for me

```
<?php
system('c:/windows/notepad.exe');
?>

<?php
$command = "c:\windows\notepad.exe";
exec($command);
?>

<?php
exec('c:\windows\notepad.exe');
?>
```

waiting for your assistance

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: I assume you realise this will open `notepad.exe` on the server, and not on the client PC... Right?

Comment: for a project which i am working on it.

Comment: The first and third both work for me

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes to open on server

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is there anything to edit on php.ini, any suggestion

Comment: Correction, it worked in CLI, but it just hangs when run via the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly same thing I am facing, its hanging, waiting for localhost... kindly let me know if you find any work arround

Comment: Your web server (and PHP) process are running without a desktop session, probably under the SYSTEM or NETWORK SERVICE account. So it runs notepad but doesn't show a window in your current user desktop session.

Comment: @timclutton Is correct. If you look at Task Manager, you will see one or more `notepad.exe` running under `SYSTEM`

Comment: @RiggsFolly  not able to find notepad under task manager. for some reason its not running via script